# sqlite_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given warning

Tags: php

How can i solve this warning ?

```
        <?php
          $dir = 'sqlite:/home/ravi/public_html/db/FavoriteApps.db';
          $dbh= new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
          $query =  "SELECT * from app_category";
          foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row)
          {

                $strName = $row[1];
                error_log("".  $strName );

                }
          sqlite_close( $dbh);
       ?>
```

Comment: You are calling `sqlite_close()` on a PDO object, not on a SQLite resource as opened by `sqlite_open()`.  That won't work, and there is no need to close it manually anyway. PDO will clean up after itself.

Comment: why??????? we must have to close the database. is it close automatically?

Comment: You can close it with $dbh = NULL; But, PDO will generally clean after itself.

Comment: You only need to close it by setting to NULL if you must release the resource to save memory or something else needs to access it. Otherwise, PDO will close it when the script terminates.